# How to add space to the bottom of a page without <br>

Tags: html, css

How can I add space to the bottom of a web page, say 100 pixels, without using multiple `<br>` tags? Right now I have something like this:

```
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

and that can be annoying to read when I'm looking through code. Is there a way to do this without `<br>`, maybe with CSS?

Comment: Look into CSS Padding.

Comment: Use CSS to give the container element a `padding-bottom: 100px;` style.

Comment: yes use css margin-bottom or padding-bottom as per requirment

Answer (score 2):

You can use margin-bottom, use the class when ever you want to keep 100px gap

```
.bottom {
    margin-bottom:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but why `2px`?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do it with CSS, in the `<head>` of your HTML document simply add:

```
<style>
  body{
    margin-bottom: 100px;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use CSS' padding-bottom

```
body {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```